# Number of additive partitions

Tags: combinatorics

Show that the number of additive partitions of $n$ in which no summand appears more than $d$ times equals the number of additive partitions of $n$ in which no summand is a multiple of $d+1$.

Now I'm not sure how to deal with the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your asking perhaps you can clarify?

Answer (score 1):

It is a result known as **Glaisher’s theorem**.

I can give you an hint before giving you the complete solution : you could use the fequency notation of partitions to prove more easily this result.

A partition $n = p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n$, can be written $f_1.1+f_2.2+\dots$ or $\{ f_1,f_2,\dots\}$, where $f_i$ represents the number of times $i$ appears in the partition of $n$. For example : $5+3+2+2+1+1+1=\{3,2,1,0,1\}$.

Consider $n=l_1+l_2+\dots+l_t$, a partition of $n$ into $t$ non-multiples of $d+1$. We write $n=\{f_1,f_2,\dots\}$, where $f_i=0$ if $i$ is a multiple of $d+1$. Now we expand each $f_i$ is base $m=d+1$. $$f_1.1+f_2.2+f_3.3+\dots=(a_{1,0}m^0+a_{1,1}m^1+a_{1,2}m^2+\dots).1+(a_{2,0}m^0+a_{2,1}m^1+a_{2,2}m^2+\dots).2+(a_{3,0}m^0+a_{3,1}m^1+a_{3,2}m^2+\dots).3+\dots$$
Where $a_{i,j}\in\{0,d\}$.
Thus we have $$f_1.1+f_2.2+f_3.3+\dots=1.a_{1,0}+2.a_{2,0}+\dots+(m-1).a_{m-1,0}+(m+1).a_{m+1,0}+\dots+m.a_{1,1}+2m.a_{1,1}+\dots$$ So :
$$f_1.1+f_2.2+f_3.3+\dots=1.a_{1,0}+2.a_{2,0}+\dots+(m-1).a_{m-1,0}+m.a_{1,1}+(m+1).a_{m+1,0}+\dots$$
Where each $a_{i,j}\in\{0,d\}$, so we have a bijection between the partitions with at most $d$ times same summand and the partitions with no $d+1$ multiples.

**An other proof with generating functions.** $\prod(1+x^j+x^{2j}+\cdots+x^{dj})$ is the generating function of the number of partitions of a number where each summand appears at most $d$ times. $\prod_{d+1\nmid j}{1\over1-x^j}$ is the generating function of the number of partitions where there is no term multiple of $d+1$. By noticing tht $\prod{1-x^{(k+1)j}\over1-x^j}=\prod_{k+1\nmid j}{1\over1-x^j}$, you can prove the equality of the two generating functions, and so of the two quantities.

Comment: Can you explain the first proof further? Is $m=d+1$? What are the parts each of which appears at most $d$ times?

Comment: Okay I will ad details. wait a minute.

Comment: Can you explain the proof with generating functions further? I only now that the coefficients of the power series represent the number I'm searching for. I do not understand how you constructed them.

Comment: Hmm you need to be a bit more familiar with generating functions, you can take a look at a lecture like this one : https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/PIMS/PIMSLectures.pdf  You should be able able to understand the two formulas after reading the firts pages.